# Converting ascii value to correspondence char in a string (Ex - T104a110k115) - java

Tags: java, ascii

I have converted even position of my char to ascii value and i want these ascii value to convert back to char again.

So string value is "Thanks"

Converted value is "T104a110k115"

I want it "Thanks" again.

Program I have used... to convert

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < Str2.length(); i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        int m = Str2.charAt(i);
        sb.append(m); // add the ascii value to the string
    } else {
        sb.append(Str2.charAt(i)); // add the normal character
    }
}
System.out.println("Replaced even chart with ascii--"+sb.toString());
            
      sb.append(3);
       System.out.println("added a int--"+sb.toString());
```

Comment: So what is stopping you from extracting those numbers, parsing them, and casting the value to a `char`?

Comment: Ya. trying but output is not seems correct .. can you please help me with the program.

Comment: Where in that code is there any attempt at gathering multiple digits and parsing that as a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note:** This answer uses regular expression. If you don't know regular expressions, now might be a great time to go online and learn about it.*

In Java 11 and later, you can do it like this:

```java
String input = "T104a110k115";

String result = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(input)
        .replaceAll(r -> Character.toString(Integer.parseInt(r.group())));

System.out.println(result); // prints: Thanks
```

In older versions (Java 1.4 and later), you can do it like this:

```java
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    m.appendReplacement(buf, String.valueOf(c));
}
String result = m.appendTail(buf).toString();
```