# Is there any Solution for Converting integers in string to its ASCII characters in JAVA?

Tags: java

Question: I Have String="T104i115*115s42c111m112u116e114" i want to convert the whole string only in letters. i.e(What ever the numbers are there in odd position of string should be convert to its respective ASCII character) so that its output should be looks like "This*ss*computer"?
Can someone provide me solution for this .I have tried the below code but is not working for else part/

**INPUT**: `T104i115*115s42c111m112u116e114`
**OUTPUT**:`This*ss*computer`

```
private static String decodeAscii(String decrpt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String check=decrpt;
        String str="";
        String num="";
        for(int i=0;i<check.length();i++){
            if((check.charAt(i)>='A' && check.charAt(i)<='Z')||(check.charAt(i)>='a' && check.charAt(i)<='z')) {
                str=str+check.charAt(i);
            }
            else if(!((check.charAt(i)>='A' && check.charAt(i)<='Z')||(check.charAt(i)>='a' && check.charAt(i)<='z') || (check.charAt(i)>='0' && check.charAt(i)<='9'))) {
                str=str+check.charAt(i);
            }
            else{
                if(check.charAt(i)>='0' && check.charAt(i)<='9') {
                    num+=check.charAt(i);
                    while(true){
                        if(check.charAt(i)>='0' && check.charAt(i)<='9') {
                            num+=check.charAt(i);
                            i++;
                        }
                        else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                int number = Integer.parseInt(num);
                char c =(char)number;
                str=str+c;  
            }
            
        }
        return str;
        
    }
```

Comment: I see lots of problems with this code.  A number of them could be easily found by stepping through the code with a visual debugger.  Have you done that?  Why do you expect others to do your debugging work for you?  Get comfortable with a visual debugger, and spend time stepping through your code.  Reason what it should do at each step and then see what it actually does.  When it does something you don't expect, figure out why...

Comment: I think you can simplify your code a lot by checking for a digit right away, and handle all non-digits in the same way by just appending them to the result string.  Your `if` statements are definitely more complicated than they need to be in any case.  Be careful in what state you leave variables when you move on to the next stage, specifically `i` and `num`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting ascii value to correspondence char in a string (Ex - T104a110k115)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65367031/5221149)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.  Here are the test results from one of my many test runs.

```
Input:  T104i115*115s42c111m112u116e114
Tokens: T, 104, i, 115, *, 115, s, 42, c, 111, m, 112, u, 116, e, 114
Output: This*ss*computer
```

One good way to solve any complex problem is to break it down into steps.  You keep breaking it down until you're confident you can code each step.

As you code the steps, you run tests to make sure you're getting the results you expect.  Writing all the code and then testing it is the sure way to madness.  I'm not that good a developer that I can write hundreds of lines of code without testing.  I try to run a test for every ten to twenty lines of code that I write.

As you can guess from the test output, I parsed the input into tokens, then converted the numeric tokens to ASCII characters.  By breaking the problem into steps, I could focus on getting each step correct.

I chose to write my own parser, rather than use a complicated regular expression.  I hope my parser code is straightforward enough to understand.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ASCIIDecoder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ASCIIDecoder a = new ASCIIDecoder();
        String input = "T104i115*115s42c111m112u116e114";
        System.out.println("Input:  " + input);
        System.out.println("Output: " + a.decodeASCII(input));
    }
    
    private String decodeASCII(String decrpt) {
        List<String> parts = parseString(decrpt);
        printList(parts);
        return processList(parts);
    }

    private void printList(List<String> parts) {
        System.out.print("Tokens: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(parts.get(i));
            if (i < (parts.size() - 1)) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    private List<String> parseString(String decrpt) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        boolean isDigit = true;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < decrpt.length(); i++) {
            char c = decrpt.charAt(i);
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                if (!isDigit) {
                    add(output, builder);
                    builder.delete(0, builder.length());
                }
                builder.append(c);
                isDigit = true;
            } else {
                if (isDigit) {
                    add(output, builder);
                    builder.delete(0, builder.length());
                }
                builder.append(c);
                isDigit = false;
            }
        }
        
        add(output, builder);
        
        return output;
    }

    private void add(List<String> output, StringBuilder builder) {
        if (builder.length() > 0) {
            output.add(builder.toString());
        }
    }
    
    private String processList(List<String> parts) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
            int value = valueOf(parts.get(i));
            if (value < 0) {
                builder.append(parts.get(i));
            } else {
                char c = (char) value;
                builder.append(c);
            }
        }
        
        return builder.toString();
    }
    
    private int valueOf(String number) {
        try {
            return Integer.valueOf(number);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent answer @GilbertLeBlanc.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use a regular expression to split the input string into "digit" and "non-digit" chunks, then convert "digit" chunks to characters and join them.

Example implementation using Stream API:

```java
String str = "T104i115*115s42c111m112u116e114";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\D|\\d+)"); // a group consists of 1 non-digit or several digits

String decoded = pattern.matcher(str)
        .results()            // Stream<MatchResult> since Java 9
        .map(m -> m.group(1)) // Stream<String>
        .map(s -> s.matches("\\d+") ? (char) Integer.parseInt(s): s.charAt(0)) // Stream<Character>
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, (builder, c) -> builder.append((char) c), StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();

System.out.println(decoded);
```

Output:

```
This*ss*computer
```

Comment: If you're going for Java 9+ solution, using the [`Matcher.replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,​String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) method would be better: `decoded = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str).replaceAll(m -> Character.toString((char) Integer.parseInt(m.group())));`. In Java 11+ you can drop the `(char)` cast to gain support for characters outside the BMP, e.g. emojis.

Comment: @Andreas, shouldn't it be another answer? :)

Comment: It already is, to another question, as I showed in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014424/is-there-any-solution-for-converting-integers-in-string-to-its-ascii-characters/66014799?noredirect=1#comment116718586_66014424).

Answer (score 0):

There remain some loopholes; are there always even letters, may they not be a digit.

I assumed a single byte encoding, Latin-1, restricting the possible digits.

```
    String str = "T104i115115s42c111m112u116e114"; // Notice, not 115*115
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([3-9]\\d|[1-2]\\d\\d)"); 
    // ASCII 32-99, 100-255
    String result = pattern.matcher(str)
            .replaceAll(mr -> {
                int c = Integer.parseInt(mr.group());
                return new String(new byte[] { (byte)c }, 0, 1,
                        StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
            });
```

It still cannot guarantee a perfect solution, depending on the exact rule.